# Complex Upset in R: Sort ascending by degree and descending within degree groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetplot, complex-upset

Following the method outlined [here](https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset/issues/132), the following code produces a complex upset plot where bars are colored by degree groups (e.g., number of combinations):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ComplexUpset)

movies = as.data.frame(ggplot2movies::movies)
movies[movies$mpaa == '', 'mpaa'] = NA
movies = na.omit(movies)
genres = colnames(movies)[18:24]

query_by_degree = function(data, groups, params_by_degree, ...) {
  intersections = unique(upset_data(data, groups)$plot_intersections_subset)
  lapply(
    intersections,
    FUN=function(x) {
      members = ComplexUpset:::get_intersection_members(x)[[1]]
      degree = as.character(ComplexUpset:::calculate_degree(x))
      if (!(degree %in% names(params_by_degree))) {
        stop(
          paste('Missing specification of params for degree', degree)
        )
      }
      args = c(
        list(intersect=members, ...),
        params_by_degree[[degree]]
      )
      do.call(upset_query, args)
    }
  )
}

upset(
  movies,
  genres,
  width_ratio=0.1,
  sort_intersections="descending",
  sort_sets="ascending",
  sort_intersections_by=c('degree', 'cardinality'),
  queries=query_by_degree(
    movies, genres,
    params_by_degree=list(
      '1'=list(color='red', fill='red'),
      '2'=list(color='purple', fill='purple'),
      '3'=list(color='blue', fill='blue'),
      '4'=list(color='green', fill='green'),
      '0'=list(color='orange', fill='orange')
    ),
    only_components=c("intersections_matrix", "Intersection size")
  )
)
```

Which produces:
[image]

However, there does not seem to be a way to sort the colored bars first by degree descending, meaning the groups go from 0 to 4 and then, within those degree groups sort descending to make a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
sort_intersections = "ascending"
```

should work!